# Python Array rounding

Tags: python-3.x, multidimensional-array, rounding

unable to get one column of an array with only 1 decimal

Hi. I am a newbie in Python 3.7 so I apologize beforehand. I have two arrays both with a shape of (1000,1) (Predict and Target). The first is a list of predicted values which I rounded to 1 decimal place and verified that the numbers have only 1 sigfig. When I concatenate both arrays into one to compare the two, the first column (the one from Predict) reverts back to its original format and has over 8 sigfigs.

```
predict = model.predict_on_batch(training_data['inputs']).round(1)
targets = training_data['targets'].round(1)
test=np.concatenate((predict,targets),axis = 1)
```

I get the following

```
array([[-5.69999981, -6.1       ],
       [ 5.30000019,  5.5       ],
       [37.59999847, 37.4       ],
```

I try adding 
`np.round(test[[0]],1)` 
but that doesn't work. Can anyone guide me on how to round the fist column to just 1 sf?
Many thanks

Comment: Hello, i supposed the problem is in your first line, maybe instead of rounding in a single statement you should predict first then do the rounding. I am on my phone now so im unable to test it.

Comment: why do you care about the digits anyway? while your data are floating point numbers, they will always be somewhere in memory in binary format, no matter if displayed or not? The story is different if you want to output them as strings.

Comment: Hi MrFuppes. Well two reasons. The first is just I would like it the output to be a bit neat. The second main one is to learn more python syntax.

Comment: Hi again. I have tried doing it in two separate steps as you suggested but that also did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are selecting just the first row. You have to select it like the below.

```py
np.round(test[:,0],1)
```

Let me know if it worked

Comment: What is the output of the following? print(np.round(test[:,0],1))

Comment: This will print only the first column serially (41.1  47.6   2.2 -14.3  11.  -40.1  36. etc...) with 1 SF whereas I need to have both columns printer next to each other for comparison.

Comment: print(np.round(test,1))